# Error compiling Ruby 1.8.7 Build 160

Tags: ruby, installation, compilation, zlib

I was compiling Ruby 1.8.7's latest version yesterday (since the latest version has no binaries out yet).

I followed the instructions in the readme file, but then, when I installed ruby gems and update it, it displays the error that zlib.so cannot be found.

I am pretty sure that I already downloaded zlib libraries, etc. I also investigated the nmake logs and here's what the error looks like.

conftest.c(8) : error C2065: 'deflateReset' : undeclared identifier

Did i missed anything?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I got it figured out. You need to download the zlib binaries and place the items in the include folder into your c++ include directory. After that copy zlib1.dll in ruby\bin directory.